# PHP web page work with WAMP but fails on GoDaddy

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing a web page using HTML, PHP and Javascript. I am using aWAMP server to develop on my local machine. It has one PHP function:

```php
<?php
$file = fopen("Records.txt","r");
    $line = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
?>
```

It has one line of code within the Javascript portion to retrieve `$line`:

```js
let fullstring = <?php echo json_encode($line); ?>;
```

It works fine using WAMP. If I view the source I  see that the above line is:

```js
let fullstring = "Record1,Record2,Record3,Record4,Record5,Record6";
```

I then uploaded the file to GoDaddy and it fails. I see this instead:

```js
let fullstring = false;
```

Anyone know why? Is there a different way to retrieve a PHP variable via Javascript? Eventually I need to change this because the variable `$line` value should not be exposed to the user.

Comment: First thing I would check is whether your file `Records.txt` is capitalized properly. GoDaddy is probably on Linux, which is case-sensitive.

Comment: That was it! Thanks Jerry...

Comment: As for the second part of my question: Is there a different way to retreive a PHP variable via Javascript? Eventually I need to change this because the variable $line value should not be exposed to the user.

Comment: Remember that php and javascript are running on completely different machines. The javascript will only have what you write into the page with php. The part of your php script that reads the file is not sent in the html. Only data inserted into the html with `echo` or `print` will be visible on the client side.

Comment: `the variable $line value should not be exposed to the user`...then it should never be sent to the browser at all. Anything you put into the html or JS is potentially visible to a user who knows what they are doing. What does the variable contain which is secret? Perhaps there's another way to implement whatever you're using it for

Comment: $line contains user names and passwords. I use it in the JS to validate. It is in a text file for easy start on this project, but will be put into a database.

Comment: You must **never** send any passwords to the client side. Nor should you send usernames of other users. You do not need to validate this data on the client side, that is a server side only task, for security reasons.

Comment: OK- I got it...